# Webcam not detected on dell laptop after os upgrade from 16.04 to 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, uvc, ubuntu-20.04

I upgraded my inspirion ubuntu 16.04LTS laptop to 20.04LTS, after that I am not able to use my webcam.

I checked bios, it has camera enabled. So bios does not have any issue.
[image]

result of command lsusb -t is:

```
 lsusb -t

/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/12p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
```

Which of these entries is for webcam? And if none is related to webcam, then how and what value to add to the list of devices? Is there any technique to autodetect missing hardware in ubuntu?

Update: came across command discover

```
sudo discover
[sudo] password for ashutosh: 
 Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast 
Ethernet controller 
Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast 
Ethernet controller 
Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast 
Ethernet controller 
Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast 
Ethernet controller 
 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub 
unknown unknown 
SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Blade 
unknown unknown 
 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```